# Cordova/PhoneGap, recording audio file until silence using audioinput plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap, web-audio-api

I need to upload to a web service an audio file recorded using cordova-plugin-audioinput. I need to use this plugin and not the core one because audioinput supports the wav audio format, the only one accepted by the web service.

The "stop recording" and then "upload" actions must trigger when silence is detected (this is the task for which I need help).

I think I will have to work with the waveform in some way to detect the silence, so to learn how to read audio data in realtime while recording i'm trying to implement the following example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/fftSize

Here is my code:

```
audioinput.start({
    sampleRate: 24000,
    fileUrl: cordova.file.cacheDirectory + 'test.wav',
    streamToWebAudio: true
});

const audioCtx = audioinput.getAudioContext();
const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
analyser.fftSize = 2048;
var bufferLength = analyser.fftSize;
var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

let dataArray;

function draw () {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);
    console.log(dataArray);
    // ... draw the waveform ...
    // ... or detect silence ...
}

draw();
```

Sadly, the result is that in the draw() function all audioData's items have 128 as value.

I'm testing on-device (OnePlus 6 with Android 9 but this should work on iOS too).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't show it in your snippet, but have you forgotten to connect something to the input of the `AnalyserNode`?  If nothing is connected the input to the node is zeros, and `getByteTimeDomainData` will return 128 for these (as given by https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-analysernode-getbytetimedomaindata)

Comment: I updated the code, i hope it's more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's clearer now. But you still have the same problem: nothing is connected to your analyser node.  You need to connect something to it (`node.connect(analyser)`, for some appropriate node) tf you expect non-zero output.

Comment: i don't know how to connnect to the plugin, can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Cordova/PhoneGap, so I can't help with that.